# Why new&delete operator symbols in shared-obj is to be relocated even if they are implemented in that shared-obj?

Tags: c++, linker, relocation

I am try to implement my own c++ new & delete operators in my program as bellow:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <new>

using namespace std;

void *operator new(std::size_t size) throw(std::bad_alloc)
{
    printf("My new is called!\n");
    return malloc(size);
}

void operator delete(void *ptr) throw ()
{
    printf("My delete is called!\n");
    free(ptr);
}

void *operator new(std::size_t size, const std::nothrow_t&) throw()
{
    return malloc(size);
}

void operator delete(void *ptr, const std::nothrow_t&) throw()
{
    free(ptr);
}

void *operator new[](std::size_t size) throw(std::bad_alloc)
{
    return malloc(size);
}

void operator delete[](void *ptr) throw () 
{
    free(ptr);
}

void *operator new[](std::size_t size,
                     const std::nothrow_t&) throw()
{
    return malloc(size);
}

void operator delete[](void *ptr,
                       const std::nothrow_t&) throw()
{
    free(ptr);
}

class Object
{
public:
    Object() {}
    ~Object() {}

private:
    int a;
};

int main()
{
    Object* obj = new Object();
    if (obj)
        delete obj;

    return 0;
}
```

Then I find that, if the program is built out as:
-- an exe, then my new/delete is called as expected
-- but,, a shared-object, then symbols of new & delete is to be relocated, so in my env when this so is loaded by dlopen in another program then the new & delete will be mapped to another program's new & delete...

The detailed information is as bellow...

1. build out an exe:

   gcc -m32 -c main.cpp
   gcc -m32 main.o -o main.exe

   $ ./main.exe
   My new is called!
   My delete is called!

   $ objdump -d main.exe
    080484ac :
    80484ac:       55                      push   %ebp
    80484ad:       89 e5                   mov    %esp,%ebp
    80484af:       53                      push   %ebx
    80484b0:       83 ec 24                sub    $0x24,%esp
    80484b3:       83 e4 f0                and    $0xfffffff0,%esp
    80484b6:       b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
    80484bb:       83 c0 0f                add    $0xf,%eax
    80484be:       83 c0 0f                add    $0xf,%eax
    80484c1:       c1 e8 04                shr    $0x4,%eax
    80484c4:       c1 e0 04                shl    $0x4,%eax
    80484c7:       29 c4                   sub    %eax,%esp
    80484c9:       c7 04 24 04 00 00 00    movl   $0x4,(%esp)
    **80484d0:       e8 1f ff ff ff          call   80483f4 <_Znwj>**   --> new: expected!!
    80484d5:       89 c3                   mov    %eax,%ebx
    80484d7:       89 1c 24                mov    %ebx,(%esp)
    80484da:       e8 35 00 00 00          call   8048514 <_ZN6ObjectC1Ev>
    80484df:       89 5d f8                mov    %ebx,-0x8(%ebp)
    80484e2:       83 7d f8 00             cmpl   $0x0,-0x8(%ebp)
    80484e6:       74 22                   je     804850a 
    80484e8:       8b 45 f8                mov    -0x8(%ebp),%eax
    80484eb:       89 45 e8                mov    %eax,-0x18(%ebp)
    80484ee:       83 7d e8 00             cmpl   $0x0,-0x18(%ebp)
    80484f2:       74 16                   je     804850a 
    80484f4:       8b 45 e8                mov    -0x18(%ebp),%eax
    80484f7:       89 04 24                mov    %eax,(%esp)
    80484fa:       e8 1b 00 00 00          call   804851a <_ZN6ObjectD1Ev>
    80484ff:       8b 45 e8                mov    -0x18(%ebp),%eax
    8048502:       89 04 24                mov    %eax,(%esp)
    **8048505:       e8 0a ff ff ff          call   8048414 <_ZdlPv>** --> delete: expected
2. build out a shared object:

   gcc -m32 -c main.cpp
   gcc --shared -m32 main.o -o main.so

   $ objdump -d main.so
   000006d4 :
    6d4:   55                      push   %ebp
    6d5:   89 e5                   mov    %esp,%ebp
    6d7:   53                      push   %ebx
    6d8:   83 ec 24                sub    $0x24,%esp
    6db:   83 e4 f0                and    $0xfffffff0,%esp
    6de:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
    6e3:   83 c0 0f                add    $0xf,%eax
    6e6:   83 c0 0f                add    $0xf,%eax
    6e9:   c1 e8 04                shr    $0x4,%eax
    6ec:   c1 e0 04                shl    $0x4,%eax
    6ef:   29 c4                   sub    %eax,%esp
    6f1:   c7 04 24 04 00 00 00    movl   $0x4,(%esp)
    **6f8:   e8 fc ff ff ff          call   6f9**      ---> new: to be relocated, unexpected :(
    6fd:   89 c3                   mov    %eax,%ebx
    6ff:   89 1c 24                mov    %ebx,(%esp)
    702:   e8 fc ff ff ff          call   703 
    707:   89 5d f8                mov    %ebx,-0x8(%ebp)
    70a:   83 7d f8 00             cmpl   $0x0,-0x8(%ebp)
    70e:   74 22                   je     732 
    710:   8b 45 f8                mov    -0x8(%ebp),%eax
    713:   89 45 e8                mov    %eax,-0x18(%ebp)
    716:   83 7d e8 00             cmpl   $0x0,-0x18(%ebp)
    71a:   74 16                   je     732 
    71c:   8b 45 e8                mov    -0x18(%ebp),%eax
    71f:   89 04 24                mov    %eax,(%esp)
    **722:   e8 fc ff ff ff          call   723**     ---> delete: to be relocated, unexpected :(
    727:   8b 45 e8                mov    -0x18(%ebp),%eax
    72a:   89 04 24                mov    %eax,(%esp)
    72d:   e8 fc ff ff ff          call   72e

Comment: What's your GCC version? I remember that one past version failed to give the default allocation functions sufficiently "weak" linkage so they could be replaced (my problem was when I used `-fwhole-program`).

Comment: gcc 4.0.4.

FYI: I also test with another functions, for example: void foo(), so that foo in the shared-object will also be relocated to the program who loading this shared-object...

Can someone share how to prevent it? as the shared-object already has the implementation of this foo, also in above case that new & delete ...

Comment: That's very old. Try it with GCC 4.6.3.

Comment: @KerrekSB What does the version of GCC have to do with *anything* in this question? Do you expect newer GCC to be any different? (It wouldn't be.)

Comment: @EmployedRussian: There's at least one bug related to the linkage of the default allocation functions that I reported and that was fixed after 4.5. No idea if it's related to *this* problem, but it's quite similar, so it's worth trying with a more recent version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> but, a shared-object, then symbols of new & delete is to be relocated

This is exactly as designed (UNIX shared libraries work very differently from Windows shared libraries in that respect).

The reason: symbol interpositioning. For example, on UNIX you can link in an alternative malloc implementation (e.g. tcmalloc) into the main executable, and *every* shared library, including `libc.so` which provides its own malloc, will call *your* malloc.

If you want to achieve Windows-like symbol binding on UNIX, the `-Bsymbolic` linker flag might do what you want (read `man ld` on your platform).

If you are on Linux or Solaris, `gcc -shared -Wl,-Bsymbolic ...` should do what you want. Beware: there are many gotcha's in going "against the system". You may come to regret trying to do it this way.

Comment: Bsymbolic is not exactly a "default" option on e.g. Solaris. Basically it disabled the namespace support of the solaris linker